# How to delete Unreachable Nodes in Docker Cloud?

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I moved a few clusters (and their nodes) in Docker Cloud to another account because we started to use the organizations feature. The nodes are already terminated on AWS, but they still have an "Unreachable" state.

I can't find a way to delete the clusters (and nodes) in Web Interface or in the CLI.

I keep on receiving the following error: 'Node Cluster Terminate Failed'.

Update: the nodes are still not terminated but i'm still paying monthly usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing the current version of docker cloud and this seems to be fixed (I can remove unreachable node).